# setting state breaks the update of input fields

Tags: reactjs, next.js, setstate

i'm running into an issue where whenever i set the const buyFormData, the array do get updated but the rest of the code ( updating the Input Fields ) stop working. there is no javascript error. The code just hangs there. on my child component, i'm able to console.log and display the new array. however since the code stop updating it only works the first time i click on a "plus" or "minus" button.

commenting :" setBuyFormData(updatedValues);" allows the inputs to update freely but never updates the values for the child component.

how do i debug this ?
There is no error in the javascript console.

I'm using NextJs 13.

Edit : Formatted the code with Prettier.
I'm a bit desperated, i've been trying to figure this out for almost a week. Any help is welcome.

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { MinusIcon, PlusIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FieldValues, useForm, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
import TicketSummaryCard from './TicketSummaryCard';

//Typing
type EleventlyEvent = {
  event: Event;
  event_title: string;
};

function TicketSelection({ event }: EleventlyEvent) {
  const readFormData = useFormContext();

  const [buyformData, setBuyFormData] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {}, [buyformData]);

  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
    {
      id: '0',
      ticketName: 'Régulier',
      description: 'Régulier',
      price: '40.00',
      limit: '5'
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      ticketName: 'Admission',
      description: 'Ceci est une description Admission',
      price: '10.00',
      limit: '10'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      ticketName: 'VIP',
      description: 'Ceci est une description VIP',
      price: '80.00',
      limit: '1'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      ticketName: 'ENFANT',
      description: 'Voici le billet pour enfant',
      price: '25.00',
      limit: '2'
    }
  ]);

  const handleTicketChange = (e: any, action: string) => {
    //Get the ticket Limit number from the input field data* attribute
    let buyLimit: number = e.getAttribute('data-limit');
    let fieldName: string = e.name;
    let fieldCurrentValue: number = parseInt(e.value);

    switch (action) {
      case 'plus':
        if (fieldCurrentValue < buyLimit) {
          let updatedValue: number = fieldCurrentValue + 1;
          e.value = updatedValue;
          setValue(fieldName, updatedValue);
        } else {
          //Error Message for Limit reached
          return;
        }
        break;

      case 'minus':
        if (fieldCurrentValue > 0) {
          let updatedValue: number = fieldCurrentValue - 1;
          e.value = updatedValue;
          setValue(fieldName, updatedValue);
        } else {
          //Error Message for Limit below minimum
          return;
        }
        break;
    }

    //After doing the maths update the buy list for the summary card
    updateBuyList();
  };

  const updateBuyList = () => {
    //Read all form
    let tempBuyList: FieldValues = readFormData.getValues();
    let updatedValues: {
      ticketName: string;
      ticketPrice: number;
      ticketNumber: number;
    }[] = [];

    for (var key in tempBuyList) {
      //Loop through the FieldValues in the forms
      if (tempBuyList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        formFields?.map((formField, index) => {
          if (key === formField.ticketName) {
            let newValues = {
              ticketName: key,
              ticketPrice: formField.price,
              ticketNumber: tempBuyList[key]
            };

            //Only add the ticket to the array if the number is defined
            if (tempBuyList[key]) {
              updatedValues.push(newValues);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
   //This breaks the rest of the form. if i update the value the forms break but the value gets passed only for the firstime.
    setBuyFormData(updatedValues);
  };

  const updateTicketNumber = (target) => {};

  const {
    register,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <>
      <main className="bg-white">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-8xl px-4 sm:px-2">
          <div className="py-12 grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 grid-rows-1 items-start gap-x-8 gap-y-8 lg:mx-0 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-12">
            <div className="col-span-7 lg:col-span-9 lg:col-start-1 lg:row-end-1">
              <h1 className="text-black font-semibold text-3xl">
                Selection de billets
              </h1>
              <div className="">
                {formFields.map((item, index) => (
                  <div
                    className="rounded-lg bg-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 my-10"
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <dl className="flex flex-wrap">
                      <div className="flex-auto pl-6 pt-6">
                        <span className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                          {item.ticketName}
                        </span>
                      </div>

                      <div className="flex-none self-end px-6 pt-4">
                        <div className="mt-5 sm:ml-6 sm:mt-0 sm:flex sm:flex-shrink-0 sm:items-center">
                          <div className="flex flex-row" key={index}>
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              onClick={(e) => {
                                handleTicketChange(
                                  e.currentTarget.nextSibling,
                                  'minus'
                                );
                              }}
                              className="rounded-sm bg-[#33DEBD] p-1.5 text-black shadow-sm hover:bg-primaryhover focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-teal-600"
                            >
                              <MinusIcon
                                className="h-3 w-3 rounded"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              />
                            </button>
                            <input
                              className="mx-auto w-12 p-0 m-0 text-center border-0 text-gray-900 bg-transparent font-semibold"
                              id={item.id}
                              data-limit={item.limit}
                              value={0}
                              {...register(item.ticketName)}
                            />
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              onClick={(e) => {
                                handleTicketChange(
                                  e.currentTarget.previousSibling,
                                  'plus'
                                );
                              }}
                              className="rounded-sm bg-[#33DEBD] p-1.5 text-black shadow-sm hover:bg-primaryhover focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-teal-600"
                            >
                              <PlusIcon
                                className="h-3 w-3 rounded"
                                aria-hidden="true"
                              />
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </dl>
                    <div className="mt-6 border-t border-gray-900/5 px-6 py-6">
                      <dt className="text-md font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                        {item.price}
                      </dt>
                      <dl className="leading-6 font-normal text-gray-500">
                        {item.description}
                      </dl>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* Ticket Price summary */}

            <div className="col-span-7 lg:col-span-7 lg:row-end-1 ">
              <TicketSummaryCard event={event} buylist={buyformData} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default TicketSelection;
```

Comment: Please use a formatter like prettier to properly indent your code as it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you an annotated version that effectively leverages React's state. I didn't change that much, actually, but most notably:

- Use a static dataset for the possible tickets and their configuration *outside* the component (this could come from an API as well).
- Create a form state by making a copy of that static state so you can use that to render your form.
- Use react-hook-form for 1) setting initial values, and 2) doing basic validations.
- Update the state when the user interacts with the form input.
- Pass along the state to the ticket summary.

I hope it helps you continue your journey to make this work. The code is available in this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-rui-xjlluj?file=/src/App.tsx) so you can play around with it.

Good luck!

Comment: This works exactly as i wanted. thank you so much for this update. I will carefully analyze and learn from it. 

Question, how was my first version flawed? i've seen you've simplified much of it but why is the code not working once i update the state  ?

Comment: I set out to answer that question but, to be honest, there was so much going on in your code that I honestly don't know what broke it. You were using useFormContext instead of useForm, you were setting a hardcoded value on the form field. Those things look off to me. But in general you're doing too much work and you're not using React (and your form lib) enough. Try to keep it simple, [avoid mutation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-functions-in-javascript/), and use state only for things that need changing. That would be my general advice. Sorry if it's not an answer to your question.